# Which data structure for fast lookup, variable length, and order?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, lookup

I will state up front this is NOT a homework problem and is part of a hobby project I am working on.  I have a working solution but I feel as though my solution is messy and space inefficient.

I have a list of items.

- The length of the list is variable.  Items are removed by index.  Items are added to the end of the list.  Items can repeat.
- When an item is looked up, it is just a check to see if it is already in the list.  Each item has a item-unique 'key'.
- Items are sorted based on a user assigned priority level.

Right now I am using two data structures to accomplish my goals.

I have an ArrayList that is sorted based on priority (for keeping order), and an ArrayList that is sorted based on the item key (for fast lookup).

Is there a single data structure that will solve this problem?  I am coding in Java if that matters.  A sorted set is almost what I want, but because there are repeats I don't think this will work

Comment: [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) maybe or [avl tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree)

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Comment: I almost think a Map would be better to be honest.

Comment: if you're using a unique key, a hashmap or variation thereof is the way to go.

Comment: A Map is a better solution, but your two ArrayLists are not inefficient.  You have two sets of pointers to the same objects.  You do have to keep your two ArrayLists synchronized.

Comment: What is priority used for?  Why do you want this list to be always sorted?  "Items are added to the end of the list" and "Items are sorted by priority level" contradict each other.  What if the item belongs in the middle of the list by its priority?  You are adding way too many constraints to your description that appear superfluous.  Please describe what you actually need from this data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want lookup by key you should use a Map of some sort.

Since you want multiple objects associated with the same key you need a map of key to a list of objects rather than a map of key to a single object.

I would use a TreeMap so that it can be sorted, where the key is your key and the value is an ArrayList for the list of objects that should be returned for that key.

You will have to implement a comparator in order to get the sorting you want.

One thing to consider when using a Map of Lists is that you need to check if the map already contains a list for that key when you want to add an item.

E.g. if your map looks like this:

```
Map<String, List<Object>> map = new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>();
```

Adding an object looks like this:

```
   public void addObject(String key, Object object) {
       List<Object> objects = map.get(key);
       if (objects == null) {
           objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
           map.put(key, objects);
       }
       objects.add(object);
   }
```

Comment: Program to the interface, `Map<String, List<Object>>` is better

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a [compound key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) in an RDBMS.  If you create an ArrayList using the compound key (priority, key), you will have a single data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about a *single* data structure but you can use an `ArrayList<>` in conjunction with a `HashSet<>`

Create a wrapper class that wraps an `Item` and a `priority` which I assume is an `int` value.

```
class ItemWithPriority
{
    private Item item;
    private int priority;

    ItemWithPriority(Item item, int priority)
    {
      this.item = item;
      this.priority = priority;
    }
}
```

Maintain an `ArrayList<ItemWithPriority>` that is always sorted based on a custom `Comparator<ItemWithPriority>` which compares based on `priority`.

Additionally maintain a `HashSet<Item>` that contains the set of all items at a given point in time.

**Insert:**

```
itemWithPriorityList.add(new ItemWithPriority(item, priority));
Collections.sort(itemWithPriorityList, new PriorityBasedComparator());
itemSet.add(item);
```

**Remove:** (Based on index)

```
Item itemToBeRemoved = itemWithPriorityList.get(index);
itemWithPriorityList.remove(index);
itemSet.remove(itemToBeRemoved);
```

**Lookup:**

```
itemSet.contains(item)
```